# Performance benefit of dividing a frequently used stored procedure into multiple stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: performance, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure `usp_appdata` that is used by our application loading screen as well as a lot of other places in the application. This SP is very resource intensive and returns a lot of data. I'm planning on making a copy of this stored procedure `usp_appdata_initial` and use it only for the application loading screen and use the original sp `usp_appdata` for all other calls. Will dividing the same procedure into multiple procedures and using each one of them for a specific purpose offer any performance benefit? Thanks!

Comment: It could provide a benefit in one circumstance. If the procedure is parameterised and the parameter values passed for `usp_appdata_initial` are in some way systemically different than the values passed for `usp_appdata` and  the two use cases would require differently shaped execution plans. But we have no reason to think this is the case based on what you have told us so far

Comment: @MartinSmith Right now it's the same parameters in both cases but we are planning on adding new functionality to the `usp_appdata_initial` which would require additional parameters and therefore it'll essentially create different plans. I'm interested in learning how having two procedures in this case would be beneficial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will dividing the same procedure into multiple procedures and using each one of them for a specific purpose offer any performance benefit?

If you're making a literal copy of the procedure and calling one instance from one call stack and the other instance from another call stack, then there should be no performance difference.

If you're refactoring out the code only needed for the loading screen in the `usp_appdata_initial` procedure, then you're reducing the amount of *work* the SQL server needs to do every time the loading screen is opened, and therefore improving resource consumption and contention on that server.

You may or may not see any direct performance improvement to the runtime of that procedure in regards to your loading screen's call stack. But you will likely at least lessen some of the load on the overall server (which may or may not be significant).

---

> When an SP is being accessed concurrently by so many call stacks, are there any locks placed on the sp itself?

When a procedure is executed, there are no locks that occur that affect other executions of the same procedure or even prevent you from altering the code of the procedure itself (no matter how frequently the procedure is ran concurrently).

Conversely, a schema modification lock **is** placed on a stored procedure when you `ALTER` the code of that procedure, which can very momentarily cause a concurrent new run of that procedure to wait for the `ALTER` to complete.

Therefore it is possible to marginally improve the execution performance of one procedure that is ran very frequently, by refactoring out code that is altered very frequently (and isn't related to that call stack) into another procedure. But an `ALTER` statement generally runs near instantaneously, so even with a very heavily utilized procedure, the gains would likely be immeasurable.

---

To get a more specific answer, we'd need to see both versions of the code, and their correlating execution plans, minimally.

Comment: Thank you! I'm making a literal copy of the procedure as of now. But the idea is to segregate the loading functionality from other call stacks. Right now, if I have to add new functionality to the loading screen, all the other call stacks get penalized even though they don't need the new functionality being added. Therefore I decided to segregate the loading screen functionality but I was curious to know if it would make any performance difference. When an SP is being accessed concurrently by so many call stacks, are there any locks placed on the sp itself?

Comment: @lifeisajourney No problem! Please see my updated answer to your question "*When an SP is being accessed concurrently by so many call stacks, are there any locks placed on the sp itself?*".